# Changing file attribute using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there away to change the file attribute of a file in multiple directory..?  Right now, i have this code..

```
Please see details below.. 

attrib -r D:\deploy\A_qa\Sample1\*.* /S /D
attrib -r D:\deploy\B_qa\Sample1\*.* /S /D
```

Now, i want to simply it by adding a for loop statement.. Is that possible?

Thanks,

link

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly iterate over subdirectories using a `FOR /D` loop. For instance, the following will iterate over subdirectories of `D:\deploy\A_qa` and display their full paths as well as their names only:

```
FOR /D %%D IN (D:\deploy\A_qa\*) DO (
  ECHO Full dir path: "%%D"
  ECHO Just the name: "%%~nxD"
)
```

You should probably issue two `FOR /D` loops, one for `A_qa` and the other one for `B_qa`, each with its own `attrib` command.

You might also want to read more about the `FOR` loop in the help, just run `FOR /?` from the command prompt.